# How to listen to a dynamically created queue?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a rabbitListener which continuously listens to user messages of a queue "user-messages" asynchronously. Everything is OK until unless queue is loaded with bulk messages. When messages in bulk published to queue, messages of the **same user** are processing first thereby messages of other users are waiting for their turn.

I can't use **Priority Queue** because all the users have equal priority. So I want to create new queues and listen to them at **runtime**. All the queues will be short-lived as soon as messages consumed. (the queue will be deleted)

On browsing, I found a queue can be dynamically created using **RabbitAdmin**. But the issues are

1. How can I make my listener listen to a new short-live (TTL) queue created at runtime?
2. How can I make the listener stop listening to a deleted queue (after TTL time) to avoid exceptions?

Currently, I'm using SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory. I've no issues to use DirectMessageListenerContainer as well. My only concern is **how to communicate about dynamic queue creation & deletion to Listener**. Thinking about to https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html (event exchange plugin).

Is there any way that spring-amqp supporting **start/stop** listening dynamic queues. Thanks in advance.

```
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory myRabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(config.getConnectionFactory());
        factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(3);
        return factory;
    }

    @RabbitListener(id = "listener", queues = {
            "#{receiver.queues()}" }, containerFactory = "myRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(QueueMessage message, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag,
            MessageHeaders headers) {
         //process message
    }


  [1]: https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html
```

Comment: hi man, you can read my article at medium. link : https://karadenizfaruk28.medium.com/rabbitmq-dynamic-queue-add-and-listen-at-runtime-with-springboot-c7d42f0447c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this geezer seems to be doing exactly that => https://karadenizfaruk28.medium.com/rabbitmq-dynamic-queue-add-and-listen-at-runtime-with-springboot-c7d42f0447c

code from the link:

- rabbitMQ config

```java
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqConfiguration implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }
    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }
    @Bean
    public RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry() {
        return new RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry();
    }
    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
        factory.setMessageConverter(consumerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(final RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setPrefetchCount(1);
        factory.setConsecutiveActiveTrigger(1);
        factory.setConsecutiveIdleTrigger(1);
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        registrar.setContainerFactory(factory);
        registrar.setEndpointRegistry(rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry());
        registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory());
    }
}
```

- interface

```java
public interface RabbitQueueService {
    void addNewQueue(String queueName,String exchangeName,String routingKey);
    void addQueueToListener(String listenerId,String queueName);
    void removeQueueFromListener(String listenerId,String queueName);
    Boolean checkQueueExistOnListener(String listenerId,String queueName);
}
```

- service

```java
@Service
@Log4j2
public class RabbitQueueServiceImpl implements RabbitQueueService {
    @Autowired
    private RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;
    @Autowired
    private RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry;

    @Override
    public void addNewQueue(String queueName, String exchangeName, String routingKey) {
        Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, true, false, false);
        Binding binding = new Binding(
                queueName,
                Binding.DestinationType.QUEUE,
                exchangeName,
                routingKey,
                null
        );
        rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
        rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(binding);
        this.addQueueToListener(exchangeName,queueName);
    }

    @Override
    public void addQueueToListener(String listenerId, String queueName) {
        log.info("adding queue : " + queueName + " to listener with id : " + listenerId);
        if (!checkQueueExistOnListener(listenerId,queueName)) {
            this.getMessageListenerContainerById(listenerId).addQueueNames(queueName);
            log.info("queue ");
        } else {
            log.info("given queue name : " + queueName + " not exist on given listener id : " + listenerId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeQueueFromListener(String listenerId, String queueName) {
        log.info("removing queue : " + queueName + " from listener : " + listenerId);
        if (checkQueueExistOnListener(listenerId,queueName)) {
            this.getMessageListenerContainerById(listenerId).removeQueueNames(queueName);
            log.info("deleting queue from rabbit management");
            this.rabbitAdmin.deleteQueue(queueName);
        } else {
            log.info("given queue name : " + queueName + " not exist on given listener id : " + listenerId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean checkQueueExistOnListener(String listenerId, String queueName) {
        try {
            log.info("checking queueName : " + queueName + " exist on listener id : " + listenerId);
            log.info("getting queueNames");
            String[] queueNames = this.getMessageListenerContainerById(listenerId).getQueueNames();
            log.info("queueNames : " + new Gson().toJson(queueNames));
            if (queueNames != null) {
                log.info("checking " + queueName + " exist on active queues");
                for (String name : queueNames) {
                    log.info("name : " + name + " with checking name : " + queueName);
                    if (name.equals(queueName)) {
                        log.info("queue name exist on listener, returning true");
                        return Boolean.TRUE;
                    }
                }
                return Boolean.FALSE;
            } else {
                log.info("there is no queue exist on listener");
                return Boolean.FALSE;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error on checking queue exist on listener");
            log.error("error message : " + ExceptionUtils.getMessage(e));
            log.error("trace : " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    }

    private AbstractMessageListenerContainer getMessageListenerContainerById(String listenerId) {
        log.info("getting message listener container by id : " + listenerId);
        return ((AbstractMessageListenerContainer) this.rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry
                .getListenerContainer(listenerId)
        );
    }
}
```